# Large reference file (800,000 lines). Store in array or use filehandle

Tags: arrays, perl, memory, file-io, size

I have a very large tab delimited file with information.

```
chr9    refFlat exon    136333685   136335910   .   +   .   gene_id "CACFD1"; transcript_id "NM_001242370"; exon_number "5"; exon_id "NM_001242370.5"; gene_name "CACFD1";  
chrX    refFlat exon    51804923    51805135    .   -   .   gene_id "MAGED4B"; transcript_id "NM_001242362"; exon_number "14"; exon_id "NM_001242362.1"; gene_name "MAGED4B";
```

I have another file with the coordinates for the search (1800 lines)

```
chr11   62105438 
chr11   85195064 
chr17   33478139 
chr21   9827089
```

I have a nested for loop in a for loop, where each line in the coordinate file searches against the reference file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict; 

    foreach(@coord){

                my @query = split(/\t/,$_);
                chomp @query; #clean up

                foreach(@ref){

                        my @ref_line = split(/\t/,$_);
                        chomp @ref_line; #clean up

                        if(($query[1] >= $ref_line[3]) && ($query[1] <= $ref_line[4])){

                                if ($query[0] eq $ref_line[0]){

                                        my @sub_ref_line = split(";",$ref_line[8]);
                                        $results {"$query[0],$query[1]"} = "$sub_ref_line[4]";
                                        next;
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
```

For the sake of speed and memory, would it be better for me to use a file handle for the reference instead of storing it in an array?

Comment: Add `use warnings;` to the beginning of your file instead of adding `-w` to the shebang (`#!`) line. You should also have `use strict;` in there as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to read the reference file into a hash first, that looks like this:

```
my %ref = (
    'chr9' => [
        'chr9    refFlat exon    136333685   136335910   .   +   .   gene_id "CACFD1"',
        # any other lines with chr9
    ],
    'chrX' => [
        ...
    ],
    ...
);
```

Then in your inner loop, you can loop over only those reference file lines that have a matching first field:

```
    foreach ( @{ $ref{ $query[0] } } ) {
```

You use only slightly more memory but if the average chr# appears 20000 times, you enter the inner loop 36 million times instead of 1.44 billion times.

To answer your actual question, reading the file in the inner loop instead of having the reference data in memory will take less memory but be very much slower.

Comment: The reason I decided to query the coordinates first instead of the chr# is because I would get less hits. Is this bad thinking? For instance, if the ref had 20,000 chr9, that's 20,000 hits, but if the ref only had 3 locations that held the coordinate, then the number of hits would be 3

Comment: that's probably true, but not significant; you still will be doing some checking for 1800*800000 combinations; just looking up in a hash all at once those 20000 and not even touching the others should make a big difference

Comment: great advice! what what a ~40min search is now at ~3min search. Wow!